# Change BigBlueButton HTML 5 Client Layout

Tags: layout, bigbluebutton

I'm trying to do some layout changes like

- Minimize public chat windows by default
- Minimize Presentation window by default

Following the [docs](http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/client-configuration.html#layouts), i tried editting `/var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/layout.xml`, and set both, `ChatWindow0` and `ChatWindow1` `hidden` property to `true` but nothing happen!

How can i create a custom layout for HTML5 Client?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information you need could be found in their Google Group. I did a little research about these, however:

- Their approach is mobile-first, and the default layout on mobile devices follows that approach. However, if you want to change this behavior, you may open  `/var/www/bigbluebutton/client/conf/layout.xml` where you can find different layouts to set. In addition, you can customize a layout in a way that fits your needs. The key part you're missing may be not reloading the application: `bbb-conf --restart`. If that doesn't work, try re-compiling the project.
- There is a [work in progress](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/bigbluebutton-dev/layout%7Csort:date/bigbluebutton-dev/D11maesZLBY/gb_FjY06AgAJ) on a **Custom Layout** feature, to compete with the same feature Adobe provides. They didn't give any information about the upcoming feature, nor a release time, though. At the moment, there's no easy way to *really* customize the layout, unless you are an expert Meteor/React.js developer and you do have time:

> There's no layout definition file in HTML5 like there is in Flash. To
>   implement it, you would need to dig into the code pretty heavily. It
>   would be too big of a change to point to one area to change. The HTML5
>   UI uses flex boxes heavily for ordering and positions.

*Chad Pilkey, from the BigBlueButton core team*

I've found it somehow hard to modify the code without breaking other parts, but you can always start by exploring the `imports` dir. where all components and styles reside. Having a look at `./bigbluebutton-html5/imports/ui/components/app/styles.scss` may give you a good overview of the general layout as well.